# how to put a search icon in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

```
<?php echo form_submit('submit','go','class ="btn"');?>
```

I have this code and i don't know how to put this `<i class="icon-search"></i>` to show me insead of go button search icon button

Comment: You can't use `form_submit()` function to generate anything other than a submit button.  Just create your custom code manually on your view.

Comment: Why not simply use `<button type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>`?

Comment: CodeIgniter has some really good documentation.  [You should consider referencing it before posting such a rudimentary question](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'button',
        'id' => 'button',
        'value' => 'true',
        'type' => 'submit',
        'content' => '<i class="icon-search"></i>'
    );

    echo form_button($data);
```